# Spawn ENOENT thrown when running Electron App packaged for distribution on OS X

Tags: electron

When I package my application up for distribution all of the buttons I have that start spawn tasks now throw ENOENT.

It ONLY happens when I package for distribution... When using electron-prebuilt I have no problems. I was hoping someone could give me some information on what could possibly be causing this! I verified both that my PATH variable includes the executable, and that the folder I am executing the ChildProcess.spawn in exists.

If any more information helps please let me know. Thanks!

http://prntscr.com/7qrzk0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two Solutions:

`gulp=spawn(process.env.SHELL, ['-c', 'cd ' + project.directory + ' && gulp'])`

OR

`childProcess.execFileSync(process.env.SHELL, ['-c', 'launchctl setenv PATH "$PATH"'])`

Comment: Can you explain what that code is and where it goes?

Answer (score 8):

I got similar error on my mac when I moved the project. I tried running 'npm rebuild' which fixed everything.

Can you try running 'npm rebuild'?

Comment: It's the OP's choice.